# how to config slurmrestd in ubuntu

Tags: slurm

After installing slurm with deepops, I realized that it was not installed while looking for slurmrestd to use the restAPI.
I have three questions for you.

1. Is slurmrestd not included in the basic package of Slurm?
2. How to set up slurmrestd
3. slurmrestd does not exist in the ubuntu20.04 apt list. Does slurmrestd not support the ubuntu20.04 version?

I upgraded the Ubuntu version and installed slurmrestd, but 'slurmrestd fatal no authentication plugins' to load problem occurred